Why does Cppcheck not like my Custom C++ iterator (says "Reference to Temporary returned")
I want to create a custom iterator that runs a bit of a code on the object before the dereferencing operator of the iterator returns the object. I have some code that works but, Cppcheck says I'm returning a temporary. I am struggling to understand what I've done wrong. Can anyone help fix my code?
Here's a simple example:
class MyCustomIterator : public std::vector<int>::const_iterator {
   public:
      MyCustomIterator(std::vector<int>::const_iterator itr)
         : std::vector<int>::const_iterator(itr) { }
      const int& operator*() const {
         const auto& out = std::vector<int>::const_iterator::operator*();
         std::cout << "value is " << out << std::endl;
         return out;
      }
   };

Cppcheck says I'm returning a reference to a temporary. The behavior of this class is given by this example:
std::vector<int> a{1,2,3};
for(MyCustomIterator itr(a.begin());itr != a.end(); ++itr) { cout << (*itr) << " is value" << endl; }

This produces the desired output (the printout within the overridden dereference operator is called before the value is returned):
value is 1
1 is value
value is 2
2 is value
value is 3
3 is value

Am I really returning a temporary here though? How can I get the thing that the base class's dereference operator method, do something with it, and then safely pass that onto the caller of my custom class's dereference operator method?
Thanks!

looks like a false positive. Whats the exact message? I'd try to see what happens when you return std::vector<int>::const_iterator::operator*();

Error is the same with that swapped in. The exact message is:
error: Reference to temporary returned. [returnTempReference]
         return std::vector<int>::const_iterator::operator*();


int is a trivial and relatively short type. The vector<int>::const_iterator returns values on dereference. Change the return type of your operator to int to get rid of it. Otherwise, learn to use std::iterator_traits.

Just a side note: you can't portably derive from vector<int>::const_iterator. It might simply be a typedef for const int*, and you can't derive from non-class types.

@Red.Wave That sounds illegal for a standard library implementation to do. Doing const int* ptr = &*vec.cbegin(); is a valid thing to do (for a non-empty vector) and must return an actual pointer to the actual first element.

@SebastianRedl that would call for language lawyer.

@Red.Wave 24.3.11.1p2 says what requirements vector meets. 24.2.2.2p7 is one such requirement, that const_iterator is a forward iterator with value type T. 25.3.5.5p1.3 specifies that for a forward iterator, reference must be an actual reference to T. And * must return reference.

I confirm that changing the return type from a const reference to a value (i.e. "const int&" to "int") makes cppcheck happy, but then my customer iterator isn't behaving how an iterator is supposed to behave, i.e. something that returns references. This breaks other parts of my code.
At this stage I am just hoping everyone agrees this is a false positive of cppcheck, and my returned reference is actually ok...

To make your code consistent, use std::iterator_traits::reference instead of ordinary reference types.

Ah thank you - seems that std::iterator_traits<const int*>::reference here makes cppcheck happy and gives the behaviour i want.

I suggest writing a self-answer containing the solution.
